# How to declare Nested fieldtype for a list of custom object?

Tags: object, elasticsearch, nested

I have a class defined with nested type for `SearchFields`. I am able to save the documents but while retrieving using `repository.findAll()` I get the error: `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: failed to map source [ {"id":"P2_P2","parentId":"P2","searchFieldsList":[{"id": "N2", "sender":false,"domains":[]}]}] to class MyFlags`

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.SearchFields` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (String)"{"id":"P2_P2","parentId":"P2","searchFields":[{"id":"N2","sender":false,"domains":[]}]}"; line: 1, column: 58] (through reference chain: com.MyFlags["searchFields"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

```
@Document(indexName = "#{@myIndexName}", type = SearchConstants.MY_TYPE)
@Setting(settingPath = SearchConstants.MY_INDEX_SETTINGS_PATH)
public class MyFlags {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Parent(type = SearchConstants.DOCUMENT_TYPE)
    private String parentId;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
    private List<SearchFields> searchFieldsList;

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public MyFlags() {
    }

    public void setParentId(String parentId) {
        this.parentId = parentId;
    }

    public String getParentId() {
        return parentId;
    }

    public List<SearchFields> getSearchFieldsList() {
        return searchFieldsList;
    }

    public void setSearchFieldsList(List<SearchFields> searchFieldsList) {
        this.searchFieldsList = searchFieldsList;
    }
}
```

The `SearchFields` class is:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class SearchFields extends Serializable {

    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Boolean)
    private boolean sender;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private Set<String> domains;

    public EmailChainSearchFields(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSender() {
        return sender;
    }

    public void setSender(boolean senderDomain) {
        this.senderDomain = senderDomain;
    }

    public Set<String> getDomains() {
        return domains;
    }

    public void setDomains(Set<String> domains) {
        this.domains = Sets.newHashSet();
    }
}
```

The mapping shown on kibana is

```
{
  "my_index_name": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "my_flags": {
        "_parent": {
          "type": "document_type"
        },
        "_routing": {
          "required": true
        },
        "properties": {
          "searchFieldsList": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "sender": {
                "type": "boolean"
              },
              "domains": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          }
      }
   }
}
```

The examples I read online (including SO) do not have list defined. Just an object is defined in place of `searchFieldsList`. So I am wondering maybe this is the place I am going wrong.

EDIT1:

match all query result in kibana on `my_type` type

```
{
        "_index": "my_index_name",
        "_type": "my_type",
        "_id": "P1_P1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_routing": "P1",
        "_parent": "P1",
        "_source": {
          "id": "P1_P1",
          "parentId": "P1",
          "emailChainSearchFields": [
            {
              "id": "N4",
              "sender": false,
              "domains": [
                "wahtever.com"
              ],
            },
            {
              "id": "N1",
              "sender": true,
              "domains": [
                "google.com"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the nested object going to be the only member? If so, then I am not sure of the value this mapping is going to provide you. You can simply have a "searchFields" doc type.

Furthermore, the name of the nested field in the mapping should be for a single doc, i.e. searchFields. And the parent doc will have multiple of these nested docs inside.

And finally, a probable solution: SearchFields class has "id" as a member whereas the nested object in the mapping does not. Also, you will need to change the mapping (searchFieldsList -> searchFields). Please try again after making these changes.

Also, make sure that each entity (main document and nested document, both) have default constructors.

Comment: The list can have multiple objects and the nested object isn't the only member. Wanted to remove clutter from the code so erased other fields. Didn't understand your second paragraph comment, can you please elaborate on `parent doc will have multiple of these nested docs inside.`?

Comment: Take this for example: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#nested-fields-array-objects

Here, the nested member name is "user" and not "userList". The main document will contain multiple entries for "user" nested documents.

Comment: I think that's just a name, we can use anything. I changed the name of my variable (removed list). Check my edit1. It shows a nested structure when i run a match_all query

Comment: After reading the edited question, I can suggest one more thing: Place a default constructor in your SearchFields class. Json parser rely on the default constructor to create the object and then use the setters to populate it.

Comment: It was a really stupid error on my part, not adding a default constructor. Thanks for your time! I really appreciate it.